# Javascript not firing another function

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to add new elements (buttons) to html file using javascript. Here is the *working* script:

```
<div id="examples">
    <?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "button";
        element.value = "Click me";
        element.id = <?=$row['id'];?>;

        var foo = document.getElementById("examples");
        foo.appendChild(element);
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

The script adding new elements to html file, but I would like to change some of the properties (for example:button size) too.

I have method *SetProperties(id, fontSize)* and if I am adding it in code when elements should be  created it doesn't work, it even do not creates that new elements. Here is the code which makes me a headache:

```
<div id="examples">
    <?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "button";
        element.value = "Click me";
        element.id = <?=$row['id'];?>;

        var foo = document.getElementById("examples");
        foo.appendChild(element);

        *SetProperties(<?=$row['id'];?>, <?=$row['fontSize'];?>);*
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

And here is the function which changes new elements properties:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetProperties(id, fontSize)
{
    var btn = document.getElementById(id);
    btn.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px;";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try using the `echo` function... Some implementations of PHP don't like `<?=`

I've noticed it doesn't work on my server when it encounters the second instance of `<?=`

Comment: Why oh why are you doing this by outputting JavaScript which modifies your DOM? Why aren't you just outputting HTML directly?

Comment: @Brian he would be seeing some very obvious problems if `<?=` weren't working.

Comment: I changed it to echo, but still if I want to change properties too it doesn't work. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're outputting an HTML5 document? Prior to HTML5, it was illegal to use a number for an element's ID.

Comment: @meagar Thank you for your comments. And yes I'm sure that it is HTML5, and just in case I tried to make id a string it still doesn't work. Also can you give me an example when you said that I should outputting html directly? For me it looks impossible because I do not know how much elements I will need.

Comment: @meagar I've made bigger mistakes. Still, something to keep in mind.

Comment: Wait, font size on a button?

Comment: @BrianHannay Yes, is that wrong?

Comment: By the way, what's the meaning of `<?=` ? (I can't find it with Google.)

Comment: @donkeydown, `<?=` is the shorthand for `<?php echo`. See http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Try setting a background. The background should disable the default style which doesn't allow font size to be larger than a certain amount.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this

```
<style>
#examples [type=button]
{
    font-size:25px;
}
</style>

<div id="examples">
    <?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "button";
        element.value = "Click me";
        element.id = <?=$row['id'];?>;

        var foo = document.getElementById("examples");
        foo.appendChild(element);

    </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I have written that example fixed, but in my application I getting that value from the database, so I can't to write such a rule as in your example.

Comment: you can add your identifier for that block here it is id="examples" you can add before your loop as a div as per your requirement..

Answer (score 0):

About your code, try using just strings for the id:

```
 element.id = "<?=$row['id'];?>";

 /* ... */

 SetProperties("<?=$row['id'];?>");
```

Because `getElementById` expects a string. In some cases JavaScript could cast the number to string, but it depends on how `getElementById` is implemented in the browser.

Besides that, the code that your are doing can be implemented in a much better way:

- Output the HTML directly
- Use CSS for changing the styles
- If you need to associate some meta-data to your button so you can refer for example to a database id, use `data` attributes, instead of messing with the ID.

For example:

```
<div id="examples">
   <?php
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
       <button class="do-something" data-row-id="<?=$row['id'];?>">Click me</button>
     <?php
     }
     ?>
</div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.do-something { /* set CSS properties */ }
```

Also if you need to add a click handler, and you have a lot of buttons, you can assign the handler to the container of buttons (the example uses jQuery):

```
 $('#examples').on('click', '.do-something', function () { /* handler */ });
```

This is more efficient than assigning the click handler for each button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetProperties(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.fontSize = 25 + "px";
}
</script>

<div id="examples">
    <?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "button";
        element.value = "Click me";
        element.id = <?=$row['id'];?>;

        var foo = document.getElementById("examples");
        foo.appendChild(element);

        SetProperties(<?=$row['id'];?>, <?=$row['fontSize'];?>);
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @meagar -- why emit JavaScript when you can do it all on the server?

Here's how you would add the elements directly on the server-side, instead of emitting JavaScript that then adds the elements on the client-side:

```
<div id="examples">
    <?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {?>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" id="<?=$row['id'];?>" />
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

and to style it, put this in the `<head>` or in your CSS file:

```
<style>
    #examples input {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You may try like this to avoid creating `buttons` at `client` side

<div id="examples">
        <?php
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {?>
            <input type="button" value="Click me" id="<?=$row['id'];?>" style="font-size: 25px;" />
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```